# Why is my terminal prompt showing as a very long command that I ran last night?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, zsh

I downloaded a large number of free data science books yesterday via a command ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/gzk4wz/50_free_machine_learning_and_data_science_ebooks/), for those of you who are interested) and as of this evening, around 15 minutes ago, my terminal is now showing the entire command as what looks like the active branch name regardless of which directory I am in (I suspect that it isn't actually the branch name, but it looks similar in the theme that I am using):

[image]

Even when changing directory, the prompt still looks the same.  I have looked at `~/.zshrc` and `~/.bashrc` but nothing appears to have changed in there since I started using my machine this evening.  It happened suddenly, even though I hadn't modified anything to do with that.

Why might something like this happen, and more importantly, how can I rectify it?

I have searched and cannot seem to find any similar problems reported.

Is this a bug in ZSH (I use Oh-My-Zsh) whereby some of the commands from one's history are used in place of the prompt?  Is there a generic solution or would I have to provide my `~/.zshrc` and `~/.bashrc` files?

This is a bit of a mystery as I'm not sure which Stack Exchange it would best fit, so I figured that AskUbuntu might be the best starting point.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 20.04.  I have updated the question.

Comment: Did you customize your `PS1` ? If you did, there is good guess that it is for the reason that is [explained here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105974/419015) (I just correct my PS1 today, it's fresh in my mind). Did the "issue" resolve itself when cleaning the prompt ? And going back when you use arrow Up to go the previous commands, then arrow Down ? If Yes, PS1 is your issue

Comment: The `PS1` was one of the few things I spotted when searching online so I checked to see if anything had changed, but it looks the same as always. Like I said, I haven't (wittingly) changed it or anything else.

Comment: @B.duGaray I had already tried clearing the prompt - it was instinctive - but the prompt remained exactly the same.  I tend to always use arrow up(s) for the previous command(s).

Comment: You mean, when you open your terminal right now, il prints you this ? Even if you run `clear` ?

Comment: That's correct. Every single time, whether I use the details terminal or Tilix, it displays this as the prompt (it doesn't actually print it to the terminal, if you look closely).

Comment: check `echo $PATH` and, in each path, if there is one of these commands somewhere.

Also, can you check in your `.bash_history` if there is a "dangerous" command ? ( `| sh `for example)

Comment: `echo $PATH` returns this: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`.  `.bash_history` doesn't seem to contain anything that shouldn't be there / "dangerous". What now?

Answer (score 1):

Having inspected `.bashrc` more closely, I determined that the cause didn't lie with that, but actually with Oh-My-Zsh.

I'm still unsure exactly what went wrong, but I removed and reinstalled Oh-My-Zsh and all appeared to be well again.

One thing I noticed after reinstallation was that the contents of `.zshrc` were doubled in the same file (as if the contents had been copied and then pasted into the same document on a new line).  As such, I deleted the uppermost one, saved changes then ran:

`source ~/.zshrc`

and my prompt returned to normal!

I then changed the theme from the default one:

`ZSH_THEME="agnoster"`

and my prompt is now precisely how I had it before the error.

If you wish to take the same route as I did, then **make a backup of your aliases as they will be lost** when uninstalling and reinstalling.  Then once you have reinstalled, simply copy and paste the aliases from your backed-up file, run `source ~/.zshrc` and your aliases should be ready to go as they were before.